# SwiftUI Preview Error: "Cannot preview in this file (Update failed)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-previews

Everytime I attempt to use SwiftUI previews I am greeted with this error. I am running Xcode 14.1 on Ventura 13.0.

[image: Error in Xcode]

[image: Diagnostic Report]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this also.  It is more than likely due to the object you are passing in (*ModelData()*).  If that has data that is NOT being created, it will post this type of error.